# How to Populate Spinner in Android using retrofit?

Tags: android

I am new to android app development and I am working on my final year project. I have been trying to get the spinner to populate from an SQL server using retrofit but I can't find any help that could solve my problem can anyone guide me? Thanks

***POjO CLASS***

```
public class Category2 {

    @SerializedName("Name")

    @Expose

    private String name;
    @SerializedName("Date")

    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("Deleted")
    @Expose
    private String deleted;
    @SerializedName("Category_id")
    @Expose
    private int categoryId;

    public Category2(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(String deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }



    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to populate spinner generally? Without retrofit?

Comment: First of all... what is the problem you mention? All you have is the data class? You didn't make any other effort?

Answer (score 0):

Well, It would be helpful if you could share more info about your project. Things like the activity / fragment where your spinner is at.

Well, the content of a spinner can be passed as argument when creating the adapter.

You can make the request using retrofit. Save the data as a Array/List. Pass it to the adapter. Set the spinner adapter.